Building a generic getObjectByID Function
I build a Swift function to get an object by id of a specific SwiftData class, which works fine. Now I try to rebuild this into a generic function to use with different classes. My code looks like this:
func getObjectByID<T: PersistentModel>(context: ModelContext, id: Int) -> T? {
        
        do {
            let predicate = #Predicate<T> {
                id == $0.id
            }
            let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<T>(predicate: predicate)
            let objects = try context.fetch(descriptor)
            return objects.first
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

A get 2 errors:

The line with id == $0.id has an error: "Operator function '==' requires that 'PersistentIdentifier' conform to 'BinaryInteger'"
The line with let objects = try context.fetch(descriptor) has an error: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Why do I get these errors and how can I solve these problems?
I tried (context: ModelContext, id: any BinaryInteger) with no success

Are you reinventing the wheel?

Additional information: The id in the model looks like this:
@Model
class Manufacturer {
@Attribute(.unique)
var id: Int = 0
...


You should rename it to something else. Don't call it id.

If you want a function for model types that uses an id of type Ìnt only then you need to limit what types the function can be used for using a where condition
func getObjectByID<T: PersistentModel>(context: ModelContext, id: Int) -> T? where T.ID == Int

Using this your code will compile.
Another option is to create a specific protocol for this that specifies the type of the id property
protocol RestApiModel: PersistentModel {
    var id: Int { get }
}

And then you declare the function as
func getObjectByID<T: RestApiModel>(context: ModelContext, id: T.ID) -> T? {


My problem is: the id in my SwiftData class is not the PersistentIdentifier but an integer, that I get from an RestAPI. So as far as I understand, I have to use a predicate to fetch the first of all the elements, that have the id set to this specific search term. registeredModel(for:) wouldn't that, or am I wrong?

@RobertKubin Answer updated

Change the type of the 2nd parameter of your function from Int to T.ID – id in Identifiable is not always Int.
func getObjectByID<T: PersistentModel>(context: ModelContext, id: T.ID) -> T?

